# Delete express application setting

Tags: node.js, express

I can set an application setting for an `express.js` app like this:

```
app.set('my-setting', myVar)
```

Is there a function to delete this setting or is it common to just call

```
app.set('my-setting', undefined)
```

to unset/delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is valid. there doesnt seem to be another.

i personally dont use express settings i use env for everything.

if i really had to use express settings, i would set them all at once. not set and reset.

according to the doc there is a special case for boolean parameters :

Calling app.set('foo', true) for a Boolean property is the same as calling app.enable('foo'). Similarly, calling app.set('foo', false) for a Boolean property is the same as calling app.disable('foo').

the doc is here https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#app.set